# Posting Soap username & password header using curl c option

Tags: c, linux, curl, soap

[image]
Hi,

How do i handle 'username' and 'password' headers while posting soap request using  c based curl option.

Request from soap ui:

00011498765432107

The above request is working fine using above soap UI tool by adding username & password headers.

When i try to handle this using "curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "admin:admin");" c API option i am facing internal server error and unknown user exception.

How to handle to exception using curl.

Thanks & Regards
praveen

Answer (score 0):

you can access the SOAP header by creating custom handler class that implements `SOAPHandler` `interface` where you can define `handleMessage` method.

Check this blog for details : [Using a Message Handler to alter the SOAP Header in a Web Service Client](http://www.javadb.com/using-a-message-handler-to-alter-the-soap-header-in-a-web-service-client/)